# Android prevent UI thread from stalling when appending views

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm building an app that requires me to append a bunch of views into a scrollView (as many as 70) based on the data the server sends back.  An abbreviated version of how I am appending them looks like this.

```
    if (mWallPosts != null) {
        for (Map.Entry entry : mWallPosts.entrySet()) {
            addPostToView((DataClass) entry.getValue(), (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), mViewGroup);
        }
    }
```

and this being the addPostToView method call

```
    View postView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wall_post, container, false);
    LinearLayout containerView = (LinearLayout) mWallView.findViewById(R.id.wall_content);
    containerView.addView(postView);
```

There is more work that goes on, but it is irrelevant for the purpose of this post. I am also using a NavgationDrawer and the problem I am having is that when I navigate to this item the animation of closing the drawer isn't smooth (it kind of hangs for a second and snaps shut) It's pretty obvious to me that this is caused by the fact that this appending and the closing of the drawer are happening on the same thread, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.  If I could figure out how to delay the append or something like that it would probably help.  I don't think async would be of any use since it is ultimately going to run on the UI thread.

Comment: Well if you're doing the animation at the same time you're adding it, there's no way you're going to avoid the choppy issue. Have you considered adding the Views after the animation? Or even add them as they're coming in, instead of all at once?

Comment: This is going to be choppy no matter what like @Guardanis said.  Inflating the views can be costly.  Could you do the animation and have the views show up as they are filled?  Also maybe you should stop loading all the views at once and only load the views that are visible and possibly will be visible shortly.  You don't need to create all 70 views at once.  Maybe 10 views at a time depending on the views.

Comment: Yes... My question was more about how to delay the animation.. Is there something like a sleep or wait function?

Comment: If you're adding a bunch of views to a scrollview, that sounds a lot like a ListView, which will have much better performance.

Comment: What @Krylez said is correct; you should probably be using a ListView with an ArrayAdapter of data and use the ListView/Adapter's ability to efficiently load and display the proper data when it should be visible by overriding the getView() method in the adapter. A ListView will also re-use views, so you won't be creating 70 every time; it will re-use as needed. As for delaying the animation, you can check out Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, delayMs) to start it after a certain time, although you may want to actually use a callback to not perform it until the data is actually loaded.

Comment: Yup... Changing it to a ListView totally solved it